# eth0 is missing after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

no eth0 is showing in ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:177503 (177.5 KB)  TX bytes:177503 (177.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:a6:c8:4a:46:4c  
          inet addr:192.168.88.43  Bcast:192.168.88.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e08:9da1:7543:634a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21707 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11469933 (11.4 MB)  TX bytes:2012086 (2.0 MB)

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

---

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 84:a6:c8:4a:46:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-42-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.3.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:28 memory:c0500000-c0501fff
```

sudo lshw -C network | grep logical

Comment: Please show us `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lshw -C network | grep logical`.

Comment: Your system seems to think that all you have is a wireless network adapter (`wlan0`). Something went strange at system startup. Look at `/var/log/kern.log*` for the beginning of the last reboot (the line with `[    0.000000]` as its time-since-reboot value. Scan the following lines for any mention of "`Network`", or any errors, or anything strange.